# Woocommerce Custom Delivary options

Tags: woocommerce

I want 2 functions in woocomerce:
1. Click and collect: This is where the customers puts in an order and comes to the store to collect it. The customer should be able to set approx time they want order to be ready for. The store should be able to set minimum time to have order ready.

With click and collect they have 16 stores so person should be able to choose store to collect and then receive a receipt for pick up at the store. They pay for goods on the website.

Each store needs to be able to receive the order either by having a dashboard or by email  system.

2. Delivery:  They will also have a delivery service where people can order larger quantities for delivery to their home or their business or event. this is more conventional eCommerce transaction.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet to add multiple locations for collection is a plugin like [Local Pickup Plus.](http://www.woothemes.com/products/local-pickup-plus/) While it's certainly possible to add this functionality in yourself I'd recommend just buying a plugin. Having built something similar I came to the conclusion that -- accounting for my hourly rate -- I had saved myself no money whatsoever by building it from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

i have created a advanced local delivery plugin, check this out [a link](http://bit.ly/wc-ldp)